# Typesafe subscription confuse

Tags: playframework, typesafe-activator, typesafe

I started to learn reactive platform and  research tutorial templates. Basic tutorial started normally.

Then I began to research reactive-maps tutorial and activator says that I need free trial subscribtion within for learning and I should pay for production subscription. I am confused. What for should I pay? Should I pay for production of project growth from basic template to reactive-maps functionality? What can prevent me to move functionality from one to basic template? What for I pay - all parts of reactive is opensource?

Comment: Subscription give access for Typesafe Platform Repository with some additional db drivers, yes? Why it needed in reactive-maps tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://github.com/typesafehub/ReactiveMaps/issues/25).

Just obtain a free trial subscription for now and create a typesafe.properties with your subscription ID in.